# Python re.search doesn't execute

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying write a python script to find all array definition in a .c file.
here is the code:

.c file code line where it fails:
"int activeCondiList[DIAGNOSIS_ACTIVE_CONDITION_MAX_NUMBER];"

Python code:
type_para = ["int|float|double|char"]
find_array_definition = re.compile(r"(T\w*" + type_para + ")\s+?([a-zA-Z_]\w*)\s*?[\s*?([a-zA-Z_]\w*|\d*)*\s*?]\s*?=.*?;", re.M|re.S)
array_definition_result = re.search(find_array_definition, code)

The last line doesn't complete execution and I have to kill the program execution.

Any suggestions to improve the performance.

Comment: `Any suggestions to improve the performance.` ... if the script doesn't even _run_, then the first thing to do is to fix the syntax errors, before worrying about performance.

Comment: it works well if I change the code line to
"code = int activeCondiList[DIAGNOSIS_ACTIVE_CONDITION];"

Comment: I'm getting syntax error `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str` while executing `find_array_definition = re.compile(r"(T\w*" + type_para + ")\s+?([a-zA-Z_]\w*)\s*?[\s*?([a-zA-Z_]\w*|\d*)\s?]\s*?=.*?;", re.M|re.S)`. I'm using `Python 3.9.5` . OS - `Windows10 WSL`, `Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS`

Comment: Sorry for the wrong info,
correction to the object type_para = "int|float|double|char"

Comment: Below code worked fine for me. Answer is None. `#!/usr/bin/python3.9
import re
type_para = "int|float|double|char"
find_array_definition = re.compile(r"(T\w*" + type_para + "\s+?([a-zA-Z_]\w*)\s*?[\s*?([a-zA-Z_]\w*|\d*)\s?]\s*?=.*?;", re.M|re.S)
code="int activeCondiList[DIAGNOSIS_ACTIVE_CONDITION_MAX_NUMBER];"
array_definition_result = re.search(find_array_definition, code)
print(array_definition_result)
`

Comment: Thank you @DmitryMesserman for trying.
it is not working for me.
Environment used OS: Windows 10 Enterprise, IDE: Visual Studio Code version 1.63.2 Python version 3.10.2
It works for me if I reduce the string size inside the square brackets and also it returns the detected array.
Please do let me know if there is any way to improve the performance, a better pattern to search for array definition.

Comment: The schoolbook way to solve it is to use C grammar in BNF form (for example https://cs.wmich.edu/~gupta/teaching/cs4850/sumII06/The%20syntax%20of%20C%20in%20Backus-Naur%20form.htm) and write parser using Flex and Bison. It will work fast. The downside is that learning Flex and Bison will take some time.